# django split settings with inheritance: symbols not defined

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I'm trying to split the django settings into `base` and `testing`, so that pytest can run with a specific module (e.g. ue a simpler password hashing algorithm or remove password validators).

This is the settings module

```
settings
├── __init__.py
├── base.py
└── testing.py
```

init.py:

```
from settings.base import *
```

base.py is the usual settings.py

and testing.py should overwrite some specific values of base.py:

```
from settings.base import *

print(INSTALLED_APPS)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'different-static')
```

./manage.py runserver works because it's using DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='settings', which goes to **init** and reads base.

However, If I `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='settings.testing'`, it can't find symbols like INSTALLED_APPS or STATIC_ROOT.

```
NameError: name 'INSTALLED_APPS' is not defined
```

Any hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you have installed apps or static root declared in testing.py?

Comment: no, I don't. I was expecting them to be imported from base.py

Comment: nopes, you cant do that, then you need a common file from where you need to take them in both the settings. like common.py will have installed apps and in base and testing you inherit it

Comment: is that related to __init__.py? if I leave it empty it works. maybe a bad dependency resolution?

Comment: yup generally you need to keep it blank